# Ansible: parsing/concatenating output of getent module

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-template

I try to set up chroot for sftp users, so that they can see user/group names on `ls -l` as per [this article](https://sanitarium.net/unix_stuff/sftp_chroot.html). To this end I need to get output of `getent` command and place it into `/chroots/{{ user.username }}/etc/passwd` file.

I try to use Ansible to replace this command `getent passwd sftpuser > /chroots/sftpuser/etc/passwd` as follows:

```
- name: get {{ user.username }} user info
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: "{{ user.username }}"

- debug:
    var: getent_passwd

- name: create /chroots/{{ user.username }}/etc/passwd file
  lineinfile:
    path: /chroots/{{ user.username }}/etc/passwd
    line: "{{ getent_passwd | from_json }}"
    state: present
    create: yes
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

The 'getent_passwd' looks as follows:

```
ok: [cf1] => {
    "getent_passwd": {
        "testuser1": [
            "x", 
            "1001", 
            "1002", 
            "", 
            "/home/testuser1", 
            "/usr/sbin/nologin"
        ]
    }
}
```

But I get this error: `FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ getent_passwd | from_json }}): expected string or buffer"}`

1. What is the proper way to get those values supplied by `getent_passwd` into one flat string joined by ":"?
2. Is it safe to use genent module with `key: "root"` this way instead of `echo "root:x:0:0:not really root:::" >> /chroots/sftpuser/etc/passwd`?
3. one can run `getent passwd user1 user2` - is it possible to supply two keys to the ansible's getent module somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way to get those values supplied by `getent_passwd` into one flat string joined by ":"?

For example using a Jinja2 template with [`join` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ user.username }}:{{getent_passwd[user.username]|join(':')}}"
```

> One can run getent passwd user1 user2 - is it possible to supply two keys to the ansible's getent module somehow?

No. Either a single one or all.

Use an outer loop to request values in the first case, or filter the resulting list in the second.